# How do you load a groovy file and execute it

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinsfile dropped into the root of my project and would like to pull in a groovy file for my pipeline and execute it.  The only way that I've been able to get this to work is to create a separate project and use the `fileLoader.fromGit` command.  I would like to do

```groovy
def pipeline = load 'groovy-file-name.groovy'
pipeline.pipeline()
```

Answer (score 135):

If your `Jenkinsfile` and groovy file in one repository and `Jenkinsfile` is loaded from SCM you have to do:

**Example.Groovy**

```groovy
def exampleMethod() {
    //do something
}

def otherExampleMethod() {
    //do something else
}
return this
```

**JenkinsFile**

```groovy
node {
    def rootDir = pwd()
    def exampleModule = load "${rootDir}@script/Example.Groovy "
    exampleModule.exampleMethod()
    exampleModule.otherExampleMethod()
}
```

Comment: Readers, note that in the Groovy, "return this" is crucial.

Comment: @anton is it also possible to call methods from the loaded script without using ```example.``` all the time? Furthermore one might want that the loaded script can read and write variables from the outer script. Is that possible?

Comment: @nepa no, it's not possible. In order to work with variables, you must specify the method arguments

Comment: @anton well in the meantime i found the ```.&``` operator (e.g.: ```def exampleMethod = example.&exampleMethod```. that works pretty well...

Comment: @MichaelEaster yeah, I missed that a bunch. And, important: It's *outside* of the function scope

Comment: @MichaelEaster what exactly 'this' returns? If that would be gradle script, it would return an instance of a Project class as the binding. But in a plain groovy file, I couldn't figure that.

Comment: I get `NoSuchFileException`

Comment: @AntonShishkin , What is the `${rootDir}` variable, and where/how is it set? 
 Is it intrinsic to Jenkins or custom? 
 I am getting `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: rootDir for class: groovy.lang.Binding`.

Comment: Ok, so this is outdated.  Instead of `${rootDir}`, use `${workspace}`, which is set by Jenkins.  Also, be sure to uncheck "Lightweight checkout" in the pipeline job's configuration, or else your `.groovy` script(s) will not be downloaded from SCM.

Comment: So, I found a caveat -- when running 2 concurrent instances of the same job, Jenkins will append `@2` to the workspace name... however, it does not to so for the `@script` directory, meaning that `${workspace}@script/Example.Groovy` will not work when running concurrent builds.

Comment: I found a solution -- use `${jenkins_home}/workspace/${job_name}@script/Example.Groovy` instead.

Comment: What is declarative style equivalent for this?

Comment: Please note that in case the methods called on `exampleModule` will come with their own node block(s) and/or do not need a node block at all, they really should not be called from within the node block loading `Example.Groovy`.

Comment: I have a path to the pulled files including groovy (let's say it's in the root of the project) like `workspace/Job Name@script/ecb7a9317b1ad6......../Example.groovy` How can I determine or get rid of that additional automatically added folder with long `ecb7a9317b1ad6........` name?

Comment: Please tag as correct answer

Answer (score 38):

If you have pipeline which loads more than one groovy file and those groovy files also share things among themselves:

**JenkinsFile.groovy**

```
def modules = [:]
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                script{
                    modules.first = load "first.groovy"
                    modules.second = load "second.groovy"
                    modules.second.init(modules.first)
                    modules.first.test1()
                    modules.second.test2()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**first.groovy**

```
def test1(){
    //add code for this method
}
def test2(){
    //add code for this method
}
return this
```

**second.groovy**

```
import groovy.transform.Field
@Field private First = null

def init(first) {
    First = first
}
def test1(){
    //add code for this method
}
def test2(){
    First.test2()
}
return this
```

Comment: can may be return someting not same return this - for example return "This"?

Answer (score 20):

You have to do `checkout scm` (or some other way of checkouting code from SCM) before doing `load`.

Comment: This assumes the file to load is in SCM.

Comment: You are correct that if the file is in SCM, then you need to get it from there before trying to load it. But, if the library file is in the same repo as the main jenkinsfile, then you don't have to call checkout if the pipeline is configured to pull the repo automatically; in the job config.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks @anton and @Krzysztof Krasori, It worked fine if I combined `checkout scm` and exact source file

**Example.Groovy**

```
def exampleMethod() {
    println("exampleMethod")
}

def otherExampleMethod() {
    println("otherExampleMethod")
}
return this
```

**JenkinsFile**

```
node {
    // Git checkout before load source the file
    checkout scm

    // To know files are checked out or not
    sh '''
        ls -lhrt
    '''

    def rootDir = pwd()
    println("Current Directory: " + rootDir)

    // point to exact source file
    def example = load "${rootDir}/Example.Groovy"

    example.exampleMethod()
    example.otherExampleMethod()
}
```

Comment: This was what I needed to allow a Jenkins pipeline from SCM to work, now I have all my constants and functions centralized into a common Jenkinsfile.common.Groovy that is shared between my release pipeline and my integration test pipeline.

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#code-load-code-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script

Answer (score 9):

In case the methods called on your loaded groovy script come with their own node blocks, you should not call those methods from within the node block loading the script. Otherwise you'd be blocking the outer node for no reason.

So, building on @Shishkin's answer, that could look like

#### Example.Groovy

```
def exampleMethod() {
    node {
        //do something
    }
}

def otherExampleMethod() {
    node {
        //do something else
    }
}
return this
```

#### Jenkinsfile

```
def exampleModule
node {
    checkout scm // could not get it running w/o checkout scm
    exampleModule = load "script/Example.Groovy"
}
exampleModule.exampleMethod()
exampleModule.otherExampleMethod()
```

#### Jenkinsfile using `readTrusted`

When running a recent Jenkins, you will be able to use `readTrusted` to read a file from the scm containing the Jenkinsfile without running a checkout - or a node block:

```
def exampleModule = evaluate readTrusted("script/Example.Groovy")
exampleModule.exampleMethod()
exampleModule.otherExampleMethod()
```

Comment: This works perfectly, even with more complex pipeline (ie. with try/catch, stages, parallel node). Thanks for the tip!

Comment: My question is how do you create these additional groovy files using jenkins and saving them somewhere where it's accessible by the build? that's what im confused about

Comment: how does 'scm checkout' know what repo to pull from or what credentials to use?

Comment: Please check the Jenkins documentation for `checkout scm`: It just checks out whatever repository the Jenkinsfile was read from. Therefore, it will obviuosly not work when writing the Jenkinsfile in the Jenkins web UI. But anyways that you should not do for productive jobs.

Answer (score 4):

Very useful thread, had the same problem, solved following you.

My problem was: `Jenkinsfile` -> call a `first.groovy` -> call `second.groovy`

Here my solution:

**Jenkinsfile**

```
node {
  checkout scm
  //other commands if you have

  def runner = load pwd() + '/first.groovy'
  runner.whateverMethod(arg1,arg2)
}
```

**first.groovy**

```
def first.groovy(arg1,arg2){
  //whatever others commands

  def caller = load pwd() + '/second.groovy'
  caller.otherMethod(arg1,arg2)
}
```

NB: args are optional, add them if you have or leave blank.

Hope this could helps further.

Comment: A quick reminder, load() only works within node().  Second load() works because whateverMethod() is called within node().