# Dynamically load a groovy class and invoke a method in pipeline script

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jenkins, groovy, build-pipeline-plugin

I have developed groovy classes in IntelliJ IDE, I want to instantiate one of these classes in 'Pipeline script' of Pipeline plugin in Jenkins. I tried to follow the examples of 'Eval.me' and class.forName

```
Sample

package com.mycomp.tmo

/**
 * Created by
 */
public void callMe(){
    println("Hello World !")
}


def e = "callMe"
def cl = Class.forName("com.mycomp.tmo.Sample")
println(Eval.me("${c1} (${e})"))
```

Tried Below as well:

```
String cls = 'D:\\Users\\b\\IdeaProjects\\Automation\\src\\com\\mycomp\\tmo\\DBConnectionManager'

def map = ['person': ${cls}]
map['person'].newInstance()
```

Comment: the Pipeline plugin groovy sand box is simply unable to identify the class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the post I asked two weeks ago can answer your question.
[Create resusable jenkins pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38695237/create-resusable-jenkins-pipeline-script)

Comment: Hi Tim, my repository is SVN, will the same work with SVN ?

Comment: Never try it, but I guess if you put your groovy code inside that work flow folder, it should be the same.

Comment: Hi Tim, the post you shared is one way of doing this, but it is not always feasible to access the library from git, as I said my repo is SVN. After discussing within my team, we understand that this way is not feaisble for us. Is there any other way I can load the file and call the methods ?

Comment: there is another answer in that post looks like this {
  // ...your pipeline code...

  git 'http://urlToYourGit/projectContainingYourScript' //Change this to svn clone
  pipeline = load 'global-functions.groovy'
  pipeline.helloworld()    // Call one of your defined function

  // ...some other pipeline code...
}