# Use “def” keyword within declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have declarative pipeline used and have a problem to map key-value there as I can't use "def" within pipeline. I want to achieve something like this:

```
def pathTag = [:]
pathTag['myKey'] = 'myValue'
```

I will use then "pathTag" later on as input for Jenkins plugin (Influxdb).

Has anyone idea how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: This should work, especially within `script{}`. Could you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two places you can use `def` and programatic Groovy Syntax:

1. a `script` block, like `script { def myvar = "I can only be seen in my script tag }`
2. Create a function outside the `pipeline` tag, like so:

   ```
   String hello(def who) {
     return "hi, ${who}"
   }

   pipeline {
     ...
   }
   ```

The function outside the `pipeline` block may break the graphical pipeline editor in Jenkins, but if you don't use that you're probably fine.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628248/how-to-create-methods-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline/47631522#47631522)