# How do I import a Groovy class into a Jenkinfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How do I import a Groovy class within a Jenkinsfile? I've tried several approaches but none have worked.

This is the class I want to import:

**Thing.groovy**

```
class Thing {
    void doStuff() { ... }
}
```

These are things that don't work:

**Jenkinsfile-1**

```
node {
    load "./Thing.groovy"

    def thing = new Thing()
}
```

**Jenkinsfile-2**

```
import Thing

node {
    def thing = new Thing()
}
```

**Jenkinsfile-3**

```
node {
    evaluate(new File("./Thing.groovy"))

    def thing = new Thing()
}
```

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can return a new instance of the class via the load command and use the object to call "doStuff"

So, you would have this in "Thing.groovy"

```
class Thing {
   def doStuff() { return "HI" }
}

return new Thing();
```

And you would have this in your dsl script:

```
node {
   def thing = load 'Thing.groovy'
   echo thing.doStuff()
}
```

Which should print "HI" to the console output.

Would this satisfy your requirements?

Comment: This works? I get a FileNotFoundException, because in the directory on the Jenkins server there is just Jenkinsfile, but not the classfile which needs to be included.

Comment: I agree. Correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43881014/can-i-import-a-groovy-script-from-a-relative-directory-from-a-jenkinsfile

Comment: This does not work if the groovy file lives with your Jenkinsfile.
In the Jenkinsfile you may checkout a repo manually and load .groovy files from there. In this case the file _is_ found, but the following is thrown:
java.io.NotSerializableException: Thing