# Using class from another groovy file as a type in a Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm a groovy novice, so not sure if this is possible. I need something like an import, but not quite. Here is the simplified code example of what I'm trying to do:

in file FileToProcess.groovy I have

```
class FileToProcess implements Serializable {
  String FileName

  FileToProcess(fileName) {
   this.FileName = fileName;
  }
}
```

and then in a JenkinsFile I want to do something like

```
F1 = new FileToProcess('A');
List<FileToProcess> allFiles = new ArrayList<FileToProcess>();
allFiles.add(F1);
​for (FileToProcess file : allFiles) {
    System.out.println(file.FileName);
}
```

Now, on StackOverflow I've found examples of how to instantiate a class from another file, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811293/how-to-import-a-file-of-classes-in-a-jenkins-pipeline) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208791/how-do-i-import-a-groovy-class-into-a-jenkinfile), and that solves the line

```
F1 = new FileToProcess('A');
```

but it does not show how to use that class as a type in a declaration, for example

```
List<FileToProcess> allFiles = new ArrayList<FileToProcess>();
```

gives me "unable to resolve class FileToProcess". I also know that using a class as a type like this should work, because it does when I put the class in the same JenkinsFile, so the problem seems to be just that the class is not visible in the JenkinsFile.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you tried to setup your class libraries but I attempted the same while using a class from a pipeline shared library and it worked as intended
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

I did do it a little differently:
assuming you places the file under `src/org/Foo.groovy`

```
import org.Foo

def list = new ArrayList<Foo>
list.add(new Foo('str1'))
list.add(new Foo('str2'))
```

Comment: Well, I just have the groovy file next to the JenkinsFile, in the same folder, and they are pulled from git by Jenkins. I didn't use the shared libraries. Is that the only way to do this? I can't just use load or import it directly from the file?

Comment: I've only used the pipeline libraries option so far personally. Regardless I also think it's a bit better to manage that code that way