# Pass parameters in jenkins pipeline to internal groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

How can we pass parameters in Groovy script in Jenkins pipeline?

I have written xyz.groovy, it loads and executes fine but i would like to pass parameters in it instead of duplication of jobs. I tried passing load '../xyz.groovy' param1 param2 but no luck.

## Pipeline script:

```
node {
    load '../xyz.groovy'
}()
```

## xyz.groovy

```
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import java.net.URL

echo "\nParameters.."
echo param1
echo param2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you do something similar to this instead: [How do you load a groovy file and execute it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it)

You create methods in your groovy that you call with the parameters?

```
node {
    def script = load '../xyz.groovy'
    script.method(param1, param2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done simply by using the `${jenkins_param}` syntax

e.g

- define a string param in the Jenkins build job called `RELEASE_VERSION = "1.0"`
- reference this as `${RELEASE_VERSION}` in the groovy script

This will resolve as "1.0" when the script is running

Comment: This works because you can reference `params.xyz` with `env.xyz`. You can't access `params` outside of the pipeline (unless you pass in the params object), but you can access `env` anywhere. And, in the above example, `${RELEASE_VERSION}` really means `${env.RELEASE_VERSION}`. I haven't played with non-string params as env vars; i would assume they are transformed to strings.