# Running a groovy script through jenkinsfile which runs on a remote linux box

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a abc.groovy script which takes an argument. In my local I run it as

```
$ groovy abc.groovy <argumentValue>
```

I have stored this abc.groovy in a remote linux box under path `"/home/path/to a directory/"` and I have a jenkins pipeline job with a Jenkinsfile. How can I call abc.groovy from the JenkinsFile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GroovyShell](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html) to evaluate your script.

`GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
def execute = shell.parse(new File('/path/to/abc.groovy'))
execute.method()`

Answer (score 0):

[You'll want to use the `load` step in your Jenkinsfile like this:](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script)

```
def pipeline {
    agent 'slave'
    stages {
        stage ('Load Groovy Script') {
          steps {
              load 'path/to/abc.groovy'
          }
     }
}
```

(This example uses the declarative pipeline syntax, but is easily ported to scripted)

Note: you can't pass parameters to the groovy script in the `load` step, [however this isn't hard to work around.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40856800/pass-parameters-in-jenkins-pipeline-to-internal-groovy-script)