# Jenkins: Re-use partial pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a large amount of pipeline script.
The second half of them usually consists of the same code
The redundand code looks a bit like this

```
stage 'Windows 7'
sh 'foo'
sh 'bar'
Stage 'Windows 8.1'
sh 'foo'
sh 'somethingelse'
```

I would like to export this code fragment into a file and then reuse it when I need it.
What can I do to achieve this?
Where Do I have to store the script to make it accessible?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Pipeline Shared Groovy Library](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin) plugin.

Create a new repository, put your groovy code under (root)/var/your_code.groovy

Load the libraries with `@Library` or tick Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Pipeline Libraries -> Load Implicitly to always have the groovy code loaded

Comment: is there any simple solution like: Copy redundand code to file, load this file and execute it?

Comment: @raddirad yes there is . use https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin   . use fileLoader.fromGit to load your code and execute it

Comment: Thanks, just in case, are there any local possibilities?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: like store a Jenkinsfile in SOMEPATH locally and load it from this local patch

Comment: you can try the load command. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it)

Comment: Well worked trough a lot of traps but finally managed to get the first solution to work. Thanks :)