# Jenkins pipeline - No such file or directory when trying to load external groovy file

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I have a Jenkinfile that looks like:

```
node {

def rootDir = pwd()

def externalMethod = load("${rootDir}/ci/jenkins/shops.groovy")

// Call the method we defined in externalMethod.
externalMethod.lookAtThis("Simon")

}
```

And another file at ci/jenkins/shops.groovy

```
def lookAtThis(String whoAreYou) {
    echo "Look at this, ${whoAreYou}! You loaded this from another file!"
}
```

But Jenkins is returning the error

> java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/workspace/lush-global-soa-architecture/develop/ci/jenkins/shops.groovy (No such file or directory)

I'm not sure why it can't find this file.

Comment: Perhaps it's a unix permission issue. Does the user running the script have read access to *shops.groovy*?

Comment: I have also tried
    def externalMethod = load("${rootDir}@script/ci/jenkins/shops.groovy")

Comment: @luc14n0 I'm not sure, the worker pulls the files down from Github. I could try setting the file permissions and pushing up.

Comment: Yeah definitely give that a try. I've had issues similar to this before.

Comment: No luck @luc14n0, I've changed file permission and am still getting 'file not found'

Comment: Simon, can you expand your question by providing the output of `ls -l  /root/workspace/lush-global-soa-architecture/develop/ci/jenkins/shops.groovy` and process information about the running jenkins instance.

Comment: @Simon Iook at this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/38108449/6528221

Comment: @luc14n0 `ls -l /root/workspace/lush-global-soa-architecture/develop/ci/jenk‌​ins/shops.groovy` gave back `ls: cannot access /root/workspace/lush-global-soa-architecture/develop/ci/jenk‌​ins/shops.groovy: No such file or directory`

I also tried `ls -l /root/workspace/lush-global-soa-architecture/develop` and it gave back `total 0`

Comment: @anton That question is what got me started, but I don't seem to be able to get it working.

Comment: @Simon because your path in "load" function is wrong. You need to use path "${rootDir}@script/ci/jenkins/shops.groovy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, turns out I needed to checkout scm before I could load the file.

```
checkout scm
```