# How to call a groovy function from a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Despite following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it) and others, I am unable to successfully use a local groovy file in my Jenkinsfile (both are in the same repository).

```
def deployer = null
...
...
...
pipeline {
   agent {
      label 'cf_slave'
   }

   options {
      skipDefaultCheckout()
      disableConcurrentBuilds()
   }

   stages {
      stage ("Checkout SCM") {
         steps {
            checkout scm
         }
      }
      ...
      ...
      ...
      stage ("Publish CF app") {
          steps {
              script {
                  STAGE_NAME = "Publish CF app"
                  deployer = fileLoader.load ('deployer')

                  withCredentials(...) {   
                      if (BRANCH_NAME == "develop") {
                          ...
                          ...
                          ...
                      } else {
                          deployer.generateManifest()
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      ...
      ...
  }
```

**deployer.groovy**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def generateManifest() {
   sh "..."
   echo "..."
}
```

In the console log ([stack](http://pastebin.com/j7dWrFQq)):

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Publish CF app)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
before loading groovy file
[Pipeline] echo
Loading from deployer.groovy
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

---

**Update:**

It seems the problem was not with loading the file but rather with the contents of the file, where I execute the following which apparently does not play well:

```
sh "node $(pwd)/config/mustacher manifest.template.yml config/environments/common.json config/environments/someFile.json"
echo "..."
```

When only the `echo` is there, [this is the stack](http://pastebin.com/G5MXc7YF).

So not the `sh "node ..."` nor the `echo` work. Even changing it just to `sh "pwd"` fails as well. What could it be? the syntax in the file? the way it is called in the pipeline?

If I will make the same node call in the pipeline (for example in the `withCredentials` `if` statement, it works.

Comment: tried with single quotes? ie: `sh 'node $(pwd)/config/mustacher manifest.template.yml config/environments/common.json config/environments/someFile.json'`

Comment: @tim_yates, I will try this, but what about it also failing with a simple `echo "test"`? Update: same as before... "Cannot invoke method generateManifest() on null object"

Comment: Try replacing the `echo` with `println` --on the theory that the external file needs to be raw Groovy, not Jenkins DSL.

Comment: @MarkHu, same error (null object). At this point I will attempt a suggestion to load the file via a shared library instead of fileLoader. Lets see if it makes a difference.

Comment: ... which did not help either.

Comment: For Declarative Pipeline, you generally don't need the `checkout scm` stage - it is done automatically for you by the `agent` directive.

Comment: Right, but I did add disableDefaultCheckout. Does it still do it in this case? I wanted to have it done not-automatically

Comment: Try adding a `return this` to the bottom of your `deployer.groovy` file, or just a `this` so that the script object is returned. Also, change your `load` step to use full name of Groovy file like `load('deployer.groovy')`.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `return this` to the bottom of the `deployer.groovy` file, and then change you `load` step to use relative path and extension to groovy file like `load('deployer.groovy')`.

The `return this` is documented on [jenkins.io](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script):

> Takes a filename in the workspace and runs it as Groovy source text.
> The loaded file can contain statements at top level or just load and run a closure. For example:
>
> ```groovy
> def pipeline
> node('slave') {
>     pipeline = load 'pipeline.groovy'
>     pipeline.functionA()
> }
> pipeline.functionB()
> ```

> pipeline.groovy
>
> ```groovy
> def pipelineMethod() {
>   ...code
> }
>     
> return this
> ```

Where `pipeline.groovy` defines functionA and functionB functions (among others) before ending with `return this`

Comment: Thank you. If you will note in my question, I have added at the bottom an update where I am able to load the file, but executing code in it fails, such as even an `echo` or a `node` call. The `return` is supposed to resolve this?

Comment: @IdanAdar I _believe_ it should. I think I ran into this same issue, and adding a `return this` to the end of the file fixed it because of however Jenkins compiles it.