# Should I have multiple Release branches in GIT while integrating Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My project soon moves to Jenkins (Integrated in pipeline - I have no control over it, except for the Jenkinsfile)

The project is a Test Automation Java Selenium project, which has multiple packages, containing seperate tests - assume names module1, module2,.. modulen

Now the issue is that i am told that jenkinsfile would allow only one maven command, which in my case is 
mvn clean test -DsuiteXMLFile=xyz.xml

the xyz.xml is separate for each of module1 to modulen.

As i cant (it seems) have all modules executed in the single mvn command (or rather i want to keep them separate), team wishes to have multiple branches in GIT - each branch have different jenkinsfile - just the mvn command where i change the xyz.xml

The issue is i advocated that all the branches be features, whereas the team thinks all of them should be releases.

kindly note i am a fairly beginner level person with GIT, more so with Jenkins
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the purpose of branching? Is your dev team using them and you want to re-use their code? Because otherwise you better keep everything in 1 branch as it will be much simpler.

Comment: @PuneetArora I know [this](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) doesn't answer exactly your question but maybe it gives you a little of a headstart on branches in git.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is i advocated that all the branches be features, whereas the team thinks all of them should be releases.

You can have both: feature branches and releases branches.
Your Jenkins job could then use one set of branches or the others, with the [right filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019713/6309).