# Extract params from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that takes a bunch of params ( 50 aprox.), and other 50 for input processing:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'ansible24' }
    parameters {
            string(name: 'NAME', defaultValue: 'Nightly Valid', description: ' instance name')
    // ... x50
    }
    script {
        def filename = "configuration.yml"
        def yaml = readYaml file: filename                    
       yaml.global.name = "${params.NAME}".toString()
       // ... x50
}
```

Tomorrow, I will also have a validation for each field.

How could I extract this logic in separated files?

I already saw this: [How do you load a groovy file and execute it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it/46045382#46045382)

but it doesn't help a lot for the case of params and my case is not scripted.

Any idea ?

Comment: did you considered using of Shared Libraries https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ ?

Comment: If you load groovy files using `load ` step they can access parameters using `params` without any additional workarounds.

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko are you telling me I should let params in main file, and extract everything else in files?

Comment: @BigGinDaHouse It is not really my use case, as I will probably not reuse my code, just want to refactor it not to have a big scary pipeline file

Comment: I got it, but it is not necessary to reuse code for consuming shared libs, use them just for extractions

Comment: I find a lot of docs about scripted programming, but none for declarative. If I can't extract params, how could I extract a stage that make for example a single stage: sh 'rm -rf *'