# How to dynamically load Jenkins Pipeline file from other Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to load a Jenkins-Pipeline-File within another, already existing Pipeline. Also I'm new to Jenkins, I assume I'm just overseeing something

There's the load Command inside my main script, but it's not really behaving as it's supposed to do (pipe_name is a regular String parameter):

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Load Pipeline') {
            steps{
                load pipe_name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the Pipeline I'm about to load:

```
pipeline{
agent any
    stages{
        stage('Do Stuff') {
            steps{
                //Do Stuff     
            }
        }
        stage('Do even more stuff') {
            steps{
                #More Stuff to be done
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

However, this fails:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one pipeline { ... } block can be executed in a single run.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils.updateRunAndJobActions(Utils.groovy:298)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils$updateRunAndJobActions$8.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ModelInterpreter.call(jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy:65)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor422.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:76)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor425.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

The message seems to be rather clear, so I've decided to remove the surrounding `pipeline{}` from the loaded file only to get a different error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
... AND SO ON ...
```

Next step I removed the `agent any` on top and the `stages {}` surrounding it, hoping I'd get a cleaner file, yet just the Error message gets even more confusing.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, acceptGitLabMR, addGitLabMRComment, addInteractivePromotion, archive, artifactoryDistributeBuild, artifactoryDownload, artifactoryMavenBuild, artifactoryPromoteBuild, artifactoryUpload, bat, build, catchError, checkout, cmake, cmakeBuild, collectEnv, conanAddRemote, conanAddUser, cpack, ctest, deleteDir, deployArtifacts, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerPullStep, dockerPushStep, dockerPushWithProxyStep, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findFiles, getArtifactoryServer, getContext, git, gitlabBuilds, gitlabCommitStatus, initConanClient, input, isUnix, jiraComment, jiraIssueSelector, jiraSearch, junit, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, newArtifactoryServer, newBuildInfo, newGradleBuild, newMavenBuild, node, nodesByLabel, parallel, powershell, properties, publishBuildInfo, pwd, readFile, readJSON, readManifest, readMavenPom, readProperties, readTrusted, readYaml, resolveScm, retry, runConanCommand, script, sh, sha1, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn, tee, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, touch, unarchive, unstash, unzip, updateGitlabCommitStatus, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, writeJSON, writeMavenPom, writeYaml, ws, xrayScanBuild, zip] or symbols [all, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildingTag, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, cloud, command, configFile, configFileProvider, confluenceAfterToken, confluenceAppendPage, confluenceBeforeToken, confluenceBetweenTokens, confluenceFile, confluencePrependPage, confluenceText, confluenceWritePage, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits, defaultView, demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerfile, downloadSettings, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, envVars, environment, equals, expression, file, fileCopyOperation, fileCreateOperation, fileDeleteOperation, fileDownloadOperation, fileJoinOperation, fileOperations, fileParam, filePath, filePropertiesToJsonOperation, fileRenameOperation, fileTransformOperation, fileUnTarOperation, fileUnZipOperation, fileZipOperation, fingerprint, folderCopyOperation, folderCreateOperation, folderDeleteOperation, folderRenameOperation, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromScm, fromSource, git, gitLabConnection, github, githubPush, gitlab, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobName, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, msbuild, msbuildError, msbuildWarning, myView, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, nonStoredPasswordParam, none, not, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipeline-model, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, publishConfluence, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, recipients, remotingCLI, requestor, run, runParam, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, sshUserPrivateKey, stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, tag, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, zfs, zip] or globals [Artifactory, currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, publishConfluence, scm]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor531.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:5)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor422.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I was looking out for other options, for instance dynamically changing the Script path (as the whole Git-Repo is downloaded any way), but it doesn't seem to be possible.
[image: Script Path]

I'm starting to run out of ideas, it doesn't really matter how the other pipeline is actually loaded, but I'd like to set it up dynamically.

Thank you

Comment: Does this other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it) seem like what you are trying to accomplish? Or do you have a unique case?

Comment: Unfortunately not @kskid19 - I'm struggling as Groovy != Jenkins Groovy != Jenkins Pipeline Groovy. In Pipelines a different rules apply. I want to be able to load Pipeline-Files dynamically withing a pipeline.

Comment: I would suggest that you are trying to load an entire pipeline, but you should only be trying to load functions (which may contain stages).  Define a new function in the file you are loading and put some stages in it (not the whole pipeline block).  Assign the output of load to a variable (like its an object) and then use the variable to call the function by name. i.e. def loaded_file = load 'myExternalPipelineFile'; loaded_file.myExternalFunction();

Comment: @kskid19 - if I don't know the name of the functions (yet) as the entire pipeline is executed dynamically?

Comment: Scripted pipeline can do what you want.  The same in a declarative pipeline is still under development: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42224

Comment: I was also facing the similar issue , How this issue gets resolved ? Please let us know.

Comment: @user3543884 - I am unfortunately not sure any more what I did back then. But I try to help. I think what I wanted to do back then is essentially to trigger a pipeline when one pipeline is finished. I can't say if this fits to your use-case but in Jenkins in the pipeline-menu you can have another pipeline starting after it is finished

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can load one pipeline into another, but as `jeubank12`'s comment suggests you can use `load` to load a function full of steps into your pipeline, so your example would become:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Load Pipeline') {
            steps{
                script{
                    otherFile = load 'otherFile.groovy'
                    otherFile.doStuff()
                    otherFile.doEvenMoreStuff()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
def doStuff(){
    //Do Stuff
}
def doEvenMoreStuff(){
    //More Stuff to be done
}
return this
```

See [pipeline docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/) for how to use `load`, or alternatively you could also use [a shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108449/4163398) for more detail (and the reminder that the `return this` is crucial)

Comment: It is much simpler, if there is no need for a separate file, to just put the functions definitions on top of the file before `pipeline {`.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes if you only need to use them in one place you can do that, though I assume the reason to load from another file is so that the same steps can be shared in multiple Jenkinsfiles