# How to have modular Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to create a Jenkins declarative pipeline and would like to have the pipeline structure as following:

```
  mainPipeline.groovy
  stage1.groovy
  stage2.groovy
  stage3.groovy
```

`mainPipeline` looks like the following:

```
 pipeline {

      stages {
         stage('stage1') {
            // Call method from the file Stage1.groovy
         }
         stage('stage2') {
            // Call method from the file Stage2.groovy
         }
      }
 }
```

I have two main questions:

1. How do I link these files to a Library?
2. How do I configure Jenkins Pipeline, so that Jenkins not only knows the main JenkinsFile which is `mainPipeline` but also the submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend to separate your Jenkinsfile into separate files, since there are better options:

- You can execute jobs within your pipeline with [Pipeline: Build Step plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/). Use this to execute stages that gonna be used by multiple jobs. For example I use this to deploy my applications in a common deploy job.
- You can extend Jenkins with your own libraries, which you can load per job or for all jobs. See: [Extending with Shared Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

For both methods the defining Jenkinsfiles/Groovy scripts can come from SCM.

If you really want to load script from the project path then [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it). If you want to use multiple Jenkinsfiles from the project path, you can just add more Jenkinsfiles as "Project Recognizers" when you configure the job.