# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline Include File

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to a separate file holding variable for a Jenkins pipeline, this is because it will be used by multiple pipelines. But I can't seem to find the proper way to include it? Or if there's any way to include it?

MapA:

```
def MapA = [
    ItemA: [
        Environment: 'envA',
        Name: 'ItemA',
        Version: '1.0.0.2',
    ],
    ItemB: [
        Environment: 'envB',
        Name: 'ItemB',
        Version: '2.0.0.1',
    ]
]

return this;
```

MainScript:

```
def NodeLabel = 'windows'
def CustomWorkSpace = "C:/Workspace"

// Tried loading it here (Location 1)
load 'MapA'

pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            // Restrict Project Execution
            label NodeLabel
            // Use Custom Workspace
            customWorkspace CustomWorkSpace

            // Tried loading it here (Location 2)
            load 'MapA'
        }
    }

    stages {
        // Solution
        stage('Solution') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Using it here
                    MapA.each { Solution ->
                        stage("Stage A") {
                            ...
                        }

                        stage("Stage B") {
                            ...
                        }

                        // Extract Commit Solution
                        stage("Stage C") {
                            ...
                            echo "${Solution.value.Environment}"
                            echo "${Solution.value.Name}"
                            echo "${Solution.value.Version}"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- On Location 1 outside the pipeline and node section: it gave the below error

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.MissingContextVariableException: Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node
```

- On Location 2 inside the node section: it gave the below error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 7: Expected to find ‘someKey "someValue"’ @ line 7, column 14.
    load 'MapA'
    node {
         ^
```

Comment: you can find some good example for load dsl from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it)

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel, but is it possible to load / include external files from outside the `pipeline` or `node` section?

Comment: The file has to be somehow available in the workspace than only you can make use of load dsl.

Comment: both files are in the same directory, but as you can see from my comment `Tried loading it here (Location 1)` it gives an error when I load it

Comment: Hope my example in answer section will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your scenario in 2 ways:

**#1**

If you want you can hardcode the variable in the same Jenkins file and make use of it on your pipeline like below Example :

**Jenkinsfile** content

```
def MapA = [
    ItemA: [
        Environment: 'envA',
        Name: 'ItemA',
        Version: '1.0.0.2',
    ],
    ItemB: [
        Environment: 'envB',
        Name: 'ItemB',
        Version: '2.0.0.1',
    ]
]

pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('debug') {
            steps {
                script {
                    MapA.each { k, v ->
                        stage(k) {
                            v.each { k1,v1 ->
                                // do your actual task by accessing the map value like below 
                                echo "${k} , ${k1} value is : ${v1}"
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**#2**

If you would like to keep the variable in a separate groovy file in a gitrepo, it will be like below

Git Repo file and folder structure

```
.
├── Jenkinsfile
├── README.md
└── var.groovy
```

var.groovy

```
def mapA() {
    return [
        ItemA: [
            Environment: 'envA',
            Name: 'ItemA',
            Version: '1.0.0.2',
        ],
        ItemB: [
            Environment: 'envB',
            Name: 'ItemB',
            Version: '2.0.0.1',
        ]
    ]
} 

def helloWorld(){
    println "Hello World!"
}
return this;
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any 
  stages {
     stage("iterate") {
         steps {
           sh """
            ls -al
           """
           script {
             def x = load "${env.WORKSPACE}/var.groovy"
             x.helloWorld()
             
             x.mapA().each { k, v ->
                stage(k) {
                  v.each { k1,v1 ->
                    echo "for ${k} value of ${k1} is ${v1}"
                  }
                } //stage
             } //each
           } //script
         } //steps
     } // stage 
  }
}
```