# Jenkins lts : Problem with groovy script path in jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I just upgraded the jenkins version of our development factory to lts. We were previously in an old 2.x version

In fact we have a stage to load all scripts :

```
stage('Load Utilities Scripts') {
    checkout scm
    echo "${job_name}"
    modules.messages = load "${jenkins_home}/workspace/${job_name}@script/pipelines/utils/slack_functions.groovy"
    modules.ansible = load "${jenkins_home}/workspace/${job_name}@script/pipelines/utils/ansible_functions.groovy"
    modules.jenkins = load "${jenkins_home}/workspace/${job_name}@script/pipelines/utils/jenkins_functions.groovy"
    modules.pic_env = load "${jenkins_home}/workspace/${job_name}@script/pipelines/utils/pic_env.groovy"
    modules.maven = load "${jenkins_home}/workspace/${job_name}@script/pipelines/utils/maven_functions.groovy"
    modules.git = load "${jenkins_home}/workspace/${job_name}@script/pipelines/utils/git_functions.groovy"
}
```

it worked perfectly well except that now the scripts are positioned in

```
    /var/jenkins_home/workspace/SAGES2_BUILD_AUTO@script/357f3acc22b0fbb05a66735d46d7d7eb950a2e836ab3762b1905784bc550ee5e on builtin
    /var/jenkins_home/workspace/SAGES2_BUILD_AUTO on builtin
```

I guess it's a security evolution (i know groovy script plugin on jenkins are often deprecated but it's another problem).

How can i get this string : 357f3acc22b0fbb05a66735d46d7d7eb950a2e836ab3762b1905784bc550ee5e ? Is there any vars like job_name or jenkins_home ? Who generates this token and where ? Can i have the hand on this string ?
What does it represent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current directory and build the absolute path by appending the relative part.

```
modules.messages = load pwd() + "@script/pipelines/utils/slack_functions.groovy"
```

Or something like this

```
modules.messages = load "${WORKSPACE}@script/pipelines/utils/slack_functions.groovy"
```

It seems this has being introduced as a security improvement. So you will have to work around this like below.

```
script {
    // Locate the jenkins folder
    // This is done because there is a new sub-folder (like : 17a4ba1ed1ce777b18c5...)
    git_jenkins_folder = sh (
        script: "find " + WORKSPACE + "@script -type d -name 'jenkins' -printf '%T@ %Tc %p\n' | sort -rn | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f9",
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()
    // Load the groovy methods in groovy files
    slack = load git_jenkins_folder + "/pipelines/utils/slack_functions.groovy"
}
```

Credit: [Why does Jenkins creates a subfolder within the workspace@script folder to checkout git code instead of the workspace@script itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71143662/why-does-jenkins-creates-a-subfolder-within-the-workspacescript-folder-to-check?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The problem is there is a generated string "357f3acc22b0fbb05a66735d46d7d7eb950a2e836ab3762b1905784bc550ee5e" between @script and /pipeline.

Actually my pipeline puts groovy script in 

        
 
 workspace/SAGES2_BUILD_AUTO@script/357f3acc22b0fbb05a66735d46d7d7eb950a2e836ab3762b1905784bc550ee5e/pipelines/[...]

Comment: Wonderful answer, too bad printf isn't available on my alpine jenkins container with no root access available, and this answer is the only answer on the web regarding this issue.  Man I don't want to re-clone the repository to a subdirectory just to make this work but I guess I'll have to, or rebuild the docker container which I'm trying to avoid :(